# Java Directory Search - Text File Writer - Only 1 result appears

Tags: java, directory, filewriter

Hey so I'm currently having an issue with this code: [There is more code to this but this is the block that I need help with]

```
    File fe = new File("C:\\Users\\" + System.getProperty("user.name") + "\\desktop" + "\\SearchResults.txt");
    String customLoca = "C:\\Users\\" + System.getProperty("user.name") + "\\desktop";



    File dir = new File(customLoca);
    for (File f : dir.listFiles()){
        if (f.getName().contains(".jar"))
        if (f.getName().endsWith(".jar"))
            try{

                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fe);
                fw.write("[!]Found: " + f.getName() + "[!]");
                fw.write("\r\n");
                fw.write("[!]Found: " + f.getName() + "[!]");
                fw.close();

            }catch(Exception ex){
    }

}
}

}
```

I want it to print all the results however it only prints 1.

https://gyazo.com/406ab3039f3efa8f72d3dfff5732c088

Do you know a way I can make it so it prints all the results? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating the file writer object inside loop. so it will replace the previous result hence only the last result will be present in the `searchResults.txt`.

To fix this problem move `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fe);` outside the `for loop`

Also note that you dont need both the 2 `if` conditions.

if `if (f.getName().contains(".jar"))` is true then
    `if (f.getName().endsWith(".jar"))` also returns true, also you are missing the braces after the `if` statement.

```
File dir = new File(customLoca);
  for (File f : dir.listFiles()){
    if (f.getName().endsWith(".jar")) {
        try{

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fe);
            fw.write("[!]Found: " + f.getName() + "[!]");
            fw.write("\r\n");
            fw.write("[!]Found: " + f.getName() + "[!]");
            fw.close();

        }catch(Exception ex){
}
}
}
```